# Is it posible redistribute existing messages between all started consumers

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I have ActiveMQ Artemis. Producer generates 1000 messages and consumer one by one processing their. Now I want to process this queue with help of two consumers. I start new consumer and new messages are distributed between two runned consumers. My question: is it posible redistribute old messages between all started consumers?

Comment: What do you mean by "old messages"? Are you talking about the messages that have already been dispatched to the original consumer?

Comment: Yes. Messages that have already been dispatched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once messages are dispatched by the broker to a consumer then the broker can't simply recall them as the consumer may be processing them. It's up to the consumer to cancel the messages back to the queue (e.g. by closing its connection/session).

My recommendation would be to tune your `consumerWindowSize` (set on the client's URL) so that a suitable number of messages are dispatched to your consumers. The default `consumerWindowSize` is 1M (1024 * 1024 bytes). A smaller `consumerWindowSize` would mean that more clients would be able to receive messages concurrently, but it would also mean that clients would need to conduct more network round-trips to tell the broker to dispatch more messages when they run low. You'll need to run benchmarks to find the right `consumerWindowSize` value for your use-case and performance needs.